# Get an appointment made with Outlook with the PHP imap library

Tags: php, imap, appointment

I am trying to distill an appointment made in Outlook with the `PHP imap` library. I got as far as picking up the part which has the subtype '**CALENDAR**' but get stuck with fetching the start and end date for the appointment, since they are not in the body nor in the message headers.

Answer (score 0):

The appointment start will be in the DTSTART iCal part. Please post the MIME source of the retrieved appointment.